# I have trouble with Bean Validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, bean-validation

I'm having some trouble with the validation bean. I've changed project dependencies, I've recreated the project because I think the problem was in fact in it, being corrupted or something. I ran the project on other machines as well, but I keep having the same error. In fact, validations in the DTO do not work.

[image]

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>sustenapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>sustenApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sustenApp_API</name>
    <description>sustenApp</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum.stella</groupId>
            <artifactId>caelum-stella-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Class

```
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicUpdate
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "endereco")
public class EnderecoModel implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private String logradouro, complemento, cep, cidade, estado;
    private UUID usuario;
}
```

DTO

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import sustenapp_api.component.constraint.annotation.EnderecoVerify;
import sustenapp_api.component.constraint.annotation.UsuarioVerify;

import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@Builder
@EnderecoVerify
public class EnderecoDto {
    @NotNull @NotEmpty
    private String logradouro, complemento, cep, cidade, estado;

    @NotNull @UsuarioVerify
    private UUID usuario;
}
```

Test:

```
 @Test
    @DisplayName("Testes de Cobertura e Validação do Metodo Save")
     public void save(){
        var atual = service.save(factoryDto(usuario));
        var esperado = factoryDto(usuario);

        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals(esperado.getUsuario(), atual.getUsuario()),
                () -> assertEquals(esperado.getCep(), atual.getCep()),
                () -> assertEquals(esperado.getCidade(), atual.getCidade()),
                () -> assertEquals(esperado.getEstado(), atual.getEstado()),
                () -> assertEquals(esperado.getLogradouro(), atual.getLogradouro()),
                () -> assertEquals(esperado.getComplemento(), atual.getComplemento()),

                () -> assertThrows(
                        // @NotNull - OBSERVACAO
                        Exception.class, () -> service.save(EnderecoDto.builder().build())
                ),
                () -> assertThrows(
                        // @NotEmpty - OBSERVACAO
                        Exception.class, () -> service.save(EnderecoUtil.factoryDto(UUID.fromString(USUARIO), LOGRADOURO, COMPLEMENTO, "", CIDADE, ESTADO))
                ),
                () -> assertThrows(
                        // @NotEmpty - OBSERVACAO
                        Exception.class, () -> service.save(EnderecoUtil.factoryDto(UUID.fromString(USUARIO),"", COMPLEMENTO, CEP, CIDADE, ESTADO))
                ),
                () -> assertThrows(
                        // @NotEmpty - OBSERVACAO
                        Exception.class, () -> service.save(EnderecoUtil.factoryDto(UUID.fromString(USUARIO), LOGRADOURO, "", CEP, CIDADE, ESTADO))
                ),
                () -> assertThrows(
                        // @NotEmpty - OBSERVACAO
                        Exception.class, () -> service.save(EnderecoUtil.factoryDto(UUID.fromString(USUARIO), LOGRADOURO, COMPLEMENTO, CEP, "", ESTADO))
                ),
                () -> assertThrows(
                        // @NotEmpty - OBSERVACAO
                        Exception.class, () -> service.save(EnderecoUtil.factoryDto(UUID.fromString(USUARIO), LOGRADOURO, COMPLEMENTO, CEP, CIDADE, ""))
                ),
                () -> assertThrows(
                        // @UserVerify - OBSERVACAO
                        Exception.class, () -> service.save(EnderecoUtil.factoryDto(UUID.fromString(USUARIO), LOGRADOURO, COMPLEMENTO, CEP, CIDADE, ESTADO))
                )
            );
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Do not add content in other languages please. If you feel more comfortable asking in Portuguese, feel free to try our sister site [pt.so].

Comment: How do i understood, the problem is in `@NotNull` or `@NotEmpty` not throwing exception that you wait ?